# $n \choose k$ $= [n(n-1)\cdot\cdot\cdot(n-k+1)]/k! $ not making sense for $3 \choose 2$

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-coefficients

$n \choose k$ $= [n(n-1)\cdot\cdot\cdot(n-k+1)]/k! $ for $k \neq 0, n$

But if I plug in for $3 \choose 2$, we get $[3(2)(1)(0)]/2!$

The $0$ term is a problem, since it leads to the wrong solution, but I included it since $(n-k+1) = 3-2+1=0$.

Please advise.

Answer (score 2):

For $n=3$ and $k=2$, the last term in the numerator should be

$n-k+1=\color{blue}{3-2}+1=\color{blue}1+1=\color{red}2$,

and then you should get the correct answer:  $$\binom32 =[3(2)]/2!=3$$.

Note that $n-k+1=(n-k)+1$, not $n-(k+1)$.

Comment: Ah, I see.  I was treating it as if $(n-(k+1))=(n-k-1)=(3-2-1)=0$.  Obviously wrong, but was tempted to calculate the $(k+1)$ in isolation for some reason.  Thanks for the help!